# I lost my sidebar and header bar buttons after an error message

Tags: unity

I left my laptop on for 30 minutes, and when I came back there was an error message.

I clicked on the prompts that asked if I wanted to report the error, but after that I lost my sidebar and header bar. The only buttons left are those in my desktop.  I can't do anything now, I can't even log out and shut down properly, unless I press on the power button.

I can open the ones on the desktop but I can't minimize and exit from them. I have tried turning the laptop off and on but the problem is still there. What can I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login into a tty by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and then you can restart Unity by running:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
unity --replace &
```

You should then be able to switch back to graphical display with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: I did what you said, and this is what showed on the screen after I ran the commands:

[1] 2323
neo@neo-W251EFQ-W270EFQ:~$ stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
start: Unkonwn job: unity-panel-service
_

it just stops there. what do I do next?

Comment: You could try safely shutting down with `sudo shutdown -h now` ( itwon't save any open documents though), and try booting up and logging in again. Unity may be crashing due to a bug - if so it may be a bit difficult to fix.