# Ubuntu sidebar and close button bar does not get displayed

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unity-dash, lts

My Ubuntu 16.04 does not display the sidebar (which displays my files, Firefox, Ubuntu software center, etc.) and the close button bar. This started when I was working in terminal and installing some python dependencies and suddenly the terminal was struck. I waited for a long time but it did not get fixed. So I manually restarted my laptop through the power button and the next thing I see is this:

[image: UBUNTU LINUX 16.04]

- Image Credits: Google Images

P.S: I cannot open the terminal by any means. Is there any fix to this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** I suppose that you have mixed the permissions in your home directory. Try to open `tty1` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and execute the command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

- `chown -R` will change the ownership of the user's home directory recursively to the current `user` and its `:group`;
- `$USER` is environment variable that contains the username of the current user.
- `$HOME`  is environment variable that contains the path of the current user's home directory - execute `echo $USER $HOME` to check the values.
- You could try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open gnome-terminal window instead of tty.

Then restart the system (`sudo systemctl reboot`). Or [kill all user processes](https://askubuntu.com/a/180808/566421) (`kill -9 -1`), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and login to see the result.

---

**2.** If this doesn't help you, could try to fix some broken packages. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and execute the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

---

**3.** If all of the above does not take an effect, you could try to [reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/q/95458/566421) the desktop environment:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: I got back the sidebar but the shutdown buttons on the top right corner are still missing and even ctrl+alt+T does not open terminal. I have to manually open it from search. Any fixes for that?

Comment: @ZER-0-NE: Which from the above suggestions (1, 2 or 3) helped you? Have you restarted the system? Does the problem exist within a Guest Session (if this is enabled)?

Comment: I managed somehow with this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486711/i-lost-my-sidebar-and-header-bar-buttons-after-an-error-message)

Comment: And before I restarted I ran the command sudo apt update as you mentioned(2). It all came back. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm happy to help, @ZER-0-NE. Regards.